# How to model an objective function which is not a sum using cplex java

Tags: java, cplex

How can I model the following objective function:

`minimize Max[Ki * y[k] + sum(pi * x[k][i])]`

where k=1,..,m

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read The Tour and refer to the material from the Help Center what and how you can ask here.

Comment: A simple approach to minimising the maximum of a set of values is to add a variable and ensure that it is bigger than all the other values (e.g. adding the necessary pairwise constraints) and then minimising that new variable which is then constrained to be at least as big as any of the other values.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replay. But what do you mean by pairwise constraints. Can you give me an example

Comment: If you are trying to minimise the max of an array X, then try adding a new variable Z and add all the constraints Z>= X[i] for all i, then minimise Z.

Comment: In your case, each of X[i] is a more complicated expression, but the same principle applies.

Comment: Great! Many thanks